# Two H.264 mp4 videos: One plays in Chrome, one doesn't

Tags: google-chrome, video, h.264, mp4

I have two different videos, both (as far as I know) generally captured in the same manner, that I'm trying to play using an HTML5 video tag in Chrome. Both videos open and play perfectly in VLC, so I don't think there's any issue with a corrupted file, and both are mp4's with an H.264 format, using YUV color space. However, when I try to play one in Chrome (`Version 21.0.1180.89`) it gives me a grayed-out play button, while the other works perfectly. For reference, my OS is Ubuntu 10.10, although I've seen the same problem in newer versions of the OS. This is whether I'm loading the video into the HTML5 tag, or navigating directly to the URL where the video is being stored. I'm somewhat at a loss here, does anyone know what direction I should go to find what the significant differences are between the two videos?

#### Edit:

This one works: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/100841270/1_G101_20120914_0139PM_Course_101.mp4

This one does not: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/100841270/1_G101_20120914_1156AM_Course_101.mp4

#### Update:

It appears to have nothing to do with OS, since I've seen the same problem in both Windows and Linux. Chrome 22 beta in Ubuntu didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Can we see the videos? Or the code you're using to show them? Anything that will allow us to help you?

Comment: As far as code to show them, the problem is occurring when I load the videos directly in the browser (navigating to `https://path-to-video.mp4`), too, so I don't expect that to be much of the problem. I'll try to upload the videos somewhere that you guys can see them.

Comment: They both work for me on  Chrome `22.0.1229.56 beta`. I don't see much difference between the videos anyway, they are both encoded wih AVC High@L3.1.

Comment: Yes, them both being encoded the same way is exactly why I'm so confused at the one refusing to work for me. Thanks for trying, I'll see if I can test it out in the beta Chrome, or perhaps in a different OS.

Comment: Chromium issue 223584: [mp4 with Planar 4:2:0 YUV video neither loads nor saves in Chrome with QuickTime](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=223584)

Comment: Both videos play in my Chrome (37.0.2062.124 m) under Windows.

Comment: This was about 2 years ago, so presumably Google has since fixed whatever issue was causing this

Comment: 3 years later, the 2nd video does not play in Chrome 46 on OSX. I get a black screen.

Answer (score 6):

We had this problem and found that encoding the files in accordance with iPhone's webview's standards created files that played fine in Chrome. Chrome and iPhone webview share the same render engine, and it appears they have similar HTML5 video requirements.

Not all H.264 encoded Mp4 files are supported by Chrome and slight differences in the encoding process can produce videos that do not work. Even if the EXACT same encoding settings were used, H.264 is a variable bit-rate encoder, so different videos may exceed bitrate limits.

The encoding settings that were successful for us were:

- Only use the H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0
- Resolution below 640 x 480 and framerate up to 30 fps
- B frames are not supported in the Baseline profile.
- bitrate limit of 900kb.

Here is the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html) we used to arrive at those settings. Likely not all of these are required for Chrome, but we stuck to these rules and found that all videos worked on both platforms. Further research could likely determine the exact setting that is/was causing Chrome to not play the video.

Comment: Discussed in Super User, with reference to Chromium issue 117368: [Google Chrome issues with Planar 4:2:0 YUV .mp4 video](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/conversation/google-chrome-issues-with-planar-420-yuv-mp4-video)

Answer (score 0):

I am running Windows XP, and chrome doesn't like the second one either.

My best guess of the cause is that, the working one is only 6.4 MB, but the other one is about 21.7 MB.  Chrome might just be refusing to directly play a video that big.  Have you tried having YouTube host it, and embedding their player into your site?  That may solve the problem.  (If you are worried about random strangers watching the videos, why did you post them here?  Why would *anybody* even want to watch them?  Though, you can make videos private on YouTube, in case these are just two videos that demonstrate the same problem you are facing with the real videos.)

That may also be compounded by a different problem that exists with both videos, manifested when I try to use Windows' built-in player.  Both videos appear distorted when I use my computer's video player, stretched like 300% horizontally.

Are there other videos you have that fail in exactly the same way?  Since these are only test videos for the real thing, if this is the only video with that problem, I would not say that it really is a problem unless it recurs.  The dysfunctional video may have just run into that one-in-a-million chance that it has just the right contents for it to not work.

Comment: These are just some test videos being captured for use in a webapp I'm working on. Using another video service to host the videos isn't really an option, since there's a possibility that it will be deployed on an internal network without outside internet access, as well as some security and UI concerns.

Comment: Also, I just checked a couple of other videos we've captured since the ones I posted, and there's at least one that's over 60MB that appears to be working fine. I wonder if maybe the resolution would cause problems? Something with capturing at 480p vs 720p? I'm completely shooting in the dark, but that may have been what caused the size difference which, as you note, is basically the only difference between the two videos I posted.

Comment: Do you have others videos with the same problem?

Comment: yeah it seems to be happening on a bit less than half of the videos that we're capturing, from what I can tell

Comment: You could try converting it into a different video format, that might work.

Comment: "21.7 MB.  Chrome might just be refusing to directly play a video that big." That is one of the most ridiculous speculations I've ever read here. In fact, I read that far and then went straight for the downvote button.